# raise ActiveRecord::Rollback in after_save doesn't rollback the save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

Inside the after_save method, I have:

```
def sync
    status = Timeout::timeout(1) {
      sleep(2)
    }

  rescue StandardError => e
    puts "inside rescue"
    errors[:base] << e.message.to_s
    ApsLogger.fatal(e)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    # raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(self)
  end
```

I see `inside rescue` gets printed out, but the record is still being modified in the DB.

I tried with `raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(self)`, still doesn't work.

I expect to see the record not modified in the DB, and an error message show up in the UI.